# How to get the range of "Total Sum" column in a pivot table? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there anyway to get the range of the total sum column from a pivot table using excel vba. The range I am referring to is in the screenshot below, highlighted yellow.

[image: pivot table with the last grand total column highlighted; header and grand total row are not highlighted]

I tried using the macro recorder in excel to see if it could help answer my question. This results in me getting this.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect _
    "'Sum of Unit Cost' 'Row Grand Total'", xlDataAndLabel, True
```

however this selects a range which is more than needed as seen in the screenshot.

[image: both the data rows and the heading row are selected]

I could do something like offsetting what is selected by 2 rows and then maybe resizing it to fit the intended range but I was wondering if there was a more straight forward way of doing this.

Comment: This [`xlDataAndLabel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.selectionmode) guy looks suspiciously guilty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `xlDataAndLabel` to `xlDataOnly`; see the [XlPTSelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlptselectionmode) enum on docs.microsoft or find it in the *Object Browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>) for a list of all the available members.

Comment: Tried changing it to `xlDataOnly` and its an improvement. It leaves out the labels on top but still takes the grand total value at the bottom. Thank you. I can work with this.

Comment: @DSM remove `'Row Grand Total'` from the selection string, too.

Comment: removing 'Row Grand Total' would select all pivot table columns that are labelled 'Sum Of Unit Cost'.

Comment: Gah, this is what 2am aircode does... I guess if there's always going to be a grand total row then you can simply resize the selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to select GrandTotals. It works for rows and columns in case you also need it. The final part is to remove last row (or column).

```
Sub SelectGrandTotal()

  Dim pt As PivotTable
  Dim rColumnTotal As Range, rRowTotal As Range
  Dim numrows As Long, numcolumns As Integer
  
  Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
  
  With pt
  
    'The conditions below are checking if the GrandTotals are activated. Not really necessary in some cases.
    
    'Uncomment this block to work with Columns
    'If .ColumnGrand Then
    '  With .DataBodyRange
    '    Set rColumnTotal = .Rows(.Rows.Count)
    '    rColumnTotal.Select
    '  End With
    'End If

    If .RowGrand Then
      With .DataBodyRange
        Set rRowTotal = .Columns(.Columns.Count)
        rRowTotal.Select
        
      End With
    End If
  End With
  
    'Resizes selection and removes last Row (you can do the same for columns if necessary)
    numrows = Selection.Rows.Count
    numcolumns = Selection.Columns.Count
    Selection.Resize(numrows - 1, numcolumns).Select

End Sub
```